# How to do an update method for a nested django rest framework APi Boolean ? [OnetoOneField]

Tags: json, django, api, nested, django-rest-framework

So i have been researching about how to update the nested serializer with onetoonefield. However it has not been able to solve my problem. As i am still new to django rest framework, i am still inexperience about what is the problem as i never done an API before.

**models.py**

```
class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    membership = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class MembershipSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Membership
        fields = ('membership',)

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    membership = MembershipSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff', 'membership',)
        read_only_fields = ('id',)

    def create(self, validated_data):
        membership_data = validated_data.pop('membership')
        user = User.objects.create(**validated_data)
        Membership.objects.create(user=user, **membership_data)
        return user

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.username = validated_data.get('username', instance.username)
        instance.email = validated_data.get('email', instance.email)
        instance.password = validated_data.get('password', instance.password)
        instance.first_name = validated_data.get('first_name', instance.first_name)
        instance.last_name = validated_data.get('last_name', instance.last_name)
        instance.is_staff = validated_data.get('is_staff', instance.is_staff)
        instance.save()

        membership_data = validated_data.get('membership')
        membership_id = membership_data.get('id', None)
        if membership_id:
            membership_item = Membership.objects.get(id=membership_id, membership=instance)
            membership_item.membership = membership_data.get('membership', membership_item.name)
            membership_item.user = membership_data.get('user', membership_item.user)
            membership_item.save()
        return instance
```

**views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
serializer_class = UserSerializer
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

def get_permissions(self):
    # allow non-authenticated user to create
    return (AllowAny() if self.request.method == 'POST'
            else permissions.IsStaffOrTargetUser()),
```

**screenshot of api**

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/LmvtZ.png

As you can see above, my membership is null, i have no idea why so i tested with is_staff to check and it is using false like a normal Booleanfield. This has make me wonder what is wrong with my models for the membership boolean field.

2. Main problem
   As i am using a boolean field, i was trying to get the user membership to be updated. So i try to use PUT method and the result is nothing has change after i check the membership box and click on PUT. 
   And if i just want to update the username, i have to check on the membership box else it will give me this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLiCb.png

I have been checking online for several solution and none of them has work for me with the update method. I am also puzzle by the null value in the api for the booleanfield membership.

Comment: Do you need to extend your Membership model in the future? If not I would recommend removing it completely because with the OneToOne connection and only one attribute you can also add it to the User model.

Comment: Yes, the membership will be extend in the future for implementing the start datetime and end datetime.

Comment: Then it's still an one-to-one connection which means there is basically no reason to add another model for only three Fields. There is no benefit in that solution.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help